# Unable to install TcmTemplateBuilder on my localmachine

Tags: template-builder

[image]I am trying to run template builder(2013 sp1) on my machine, while running TcmTemplateBuilder.application (ClickOnce Application), getting the error.

Getting below error. Kindly help me.[image: Error Message]

Comment: Try in another browser or http://codeketchup.blogspot.nl/2013/06/how-to-fix-deployment-and-application.html

Comment: How are you trying to open the template builder? Are you using Internet Explorer?

Comment: By clicking on Tools>Template Builder.Yes I am using IE8.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a ClickOnce extension in your (non-IE) browser, the I'd strongly recommend that you try installing this from Internet Explorer instead.

You could also try:

1. Ensure that the URL of the Tridion Content Management Explorer (CME) is in (at least) the `Trusted Sites` or `Local Intranet` Zone in Internet Explorer. For full details of the necessary browser settings please see the [Configuring your Web browser for Content Manager Explorer](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B0393E1F-2F38-4CC0-841C-44D78AAE0B33) section of the online documentation (login required).
2. If that doesn't work, then try disabling your antivirus program (temporarily) whilst you try to install Template Builder.
3. If that still doesn't work, then you may want to consider using CCleaner (or similar) to cleanup the registry.

Please note that normal common sense rules (backing up, etc.) apply when trying items 2 or 3!

Comment: I configured as said # 1. But still it is giving me same problem. I am trying to install template builder by clicking on Tools>Template Builder in IE8. I am new to SDL tridion correct me if am wrong

Comment: Are all of your browser settings correct (Active X, Scriptlets, etc)? If so, then I can't think of anything other than what I already listed I'm afraid. You may want to raise this with Tridion Support if you don't get a successful answer here.